# URL path processing

Tags: php

I am trying to take the base URL from a site and be able to print the first and possibly second directory in the path. The code I have tested below works for anything with more than 2 directories (eg. dir/dir/title). The problem is when there is only 1 or two directories in the path (eg dir/title or just title).

```
<?php
$path = "dir/dir/dir/title";
$posl = substr($path, 0, strpos($path, "/"));
$post_strip = $posl."/";
$new_path = str_replace($post_strip, "", $path);
$new_path = substr($new_path, 0, strpos($new_path, "/"));
echo $new_path;
?>
```

I was also thinking there might be some way to split the path string at the slashes and hold each of these as an array. Therefore I can just print the specific value of the array as it corresponds to its place in the path.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: explode() on / is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url   = parse_url('http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/');

$path  = explode('/',$url['path']);

$path  = array_filter($path); //remove empty value from array

print_r($path); //output: Array ( [1] => dir1 [2] => dir2 [3] => dir3 [4] => dir4 )
```

Comment: Thanks Zulkhaery! Just what I needed. Cheers!